# Test Graphql (Graphene) Schema

Tags: flask, graphql, graphene-python

I've been looking at https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/graphene-python/latest/graphene-python.pdf for guidance on how to test that my graphql (Graphene, really since I have a python flask app) schema loads correctly. None of the versions for Graphene that I've installed support what the example shows, so I feel like I'm at a loss here.

```
from graphene.test import Client

def test_hey():
    client = Client(my_schema)
    executed = client.execute('''{ hey }''', context_value={'user': 'Peter'})
    assert executed == {
        'data': {
             'hey': 'hello Peter!'
        }
    }
```

The error that I get: `NameError: global name 'Client' is not defined` suggests that `Client` doesn't exist in the graphene realm. Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have `graphene` available within the scope of your test.

As at this [time](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/375d1f494b026d709b5a48e183b91b7988d7e304/graphene/test/__init__.py), `graphene.test.Client` exists.

Comment: Thank you for this - I feel really silly. Your solution works :)